# OpenCV - Find contours of area without clear borders

Tags: python, opencv

I'm having some images where I want to filter out the black areas using OpenCV with python. The problem is that these images comes from satellite footage and have no clear borders.

[image]
[image]

In the images added above, the first is the original image while the second is a blurred version, i'm interested in the small dark area in the middle. Ultimately I want to have this area marked as a singe contour area.

My main problem seems to be that when I use the OpenCV findContours function, I get a lot of small contours instead of one (or two) big ones.

I'm fairly new to OpenCV so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try [denoising](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/d69/tutorial_py_non_local_means.html) the image? Also is this the only image you have or is it a set of frames?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Wouldn't the second image be a denoised version? I'm only operation with one image at the time.

Comment: Yes, it would. Ok, so you can start with eroding and dilating the image.

Comment: have you tried any segmentation mechanisms..?

Comment: Have you tried changing the upper and lower thresholds for the edge detection part, before you execute the `findContours()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are just some rough results I have been able to obtain with a simple pipeline:
[image]
The code is fairly self-explanatory too

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    pass

cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.createTrackbar('high','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('low','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.namedWindow('Edges')

while(1):
    image = cv2.imread("PATH TO IMAGE HERE")
    imgray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    high = cv2.getTrackbarPos('high', 'image')
    low = cv2.getTrackbarPos('low', 'image')

    edges = cv2.Canny(imgray, low, high)
    kernel = np.ones((8, 8), np.uint8)
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    cv2.imshow('Edges', closing)

    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(closing,low,high,0)
    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    largest_area = 0
    largest_contour_index = 0
    counter = 0
    for i in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(i)
        if (area > largest_area):
            largest_area = area
            largest_contour_index = counter

        counter = counter + 1

    cv2.drawContours(image, contours, largest_contour_index, (0,255,0), 1)

    cv2.imshow('image', image)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
```

The pipeline is as follows:

1. Read smooth image
2. Convert to grayscale
3. Apply the morphological operation [closing](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/close.htm) (8x8 mask)
4. Find contours
5. Find the largest contour (area wise)

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. Easy-to-read code as well. I will need some time to fully understand the code though, since I'm new with the API. Later the issue will be how to generalize this so it can work on different images.